# Writing a dict of large dataframes to excel

Tags: python, dataframe

I am creating dicts where the dict keys are strings and the values are large-ish pandas DataFrames. I would like to write these dicts to an excel file but the issue I'm having is that when python writes the dataframe to a csv it cuts out parts. Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

def create_random_df(): 
    return(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(70,26)),columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')))

dic={'key1': create_random_df() , 'key2': create_random_df()}

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in dic.keys():
        f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key,dic[key]))
```

This sort of outputs the format I'd like except for the following:

- All of the dataframe columns are in Cell B1 and they're not complete... it's

> A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I  ...   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y
>   Z

and then the indexes and dataframe elements are all in columns A. i.e. Cells A2:A4 is

> 0   55  96  60  47  11   3   2  69  50  ...   3  23  26   3  15  53 
>   78  95  49
>
> 1   72  48  12  25  32  57  11  84   5  ...  11  43  56   0  68  55 
>   95  64  84
>
> 2   80  56  78  58  79  72  67  97  58  ...  84  34  18  21  71  20 
>   72  36  37

I'd like the dataframes to be written to the csv in their entirety and obviously the values in discrete cells

Comment: In your call `f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key,dic[key]))` you are writing two comma separated string: the key in column A and the dataframe in column B. If you want to write all the element in the dataframe columns my guess is that you will need to iterate through them. I would write first the headers of your CSV (key and then all the column name), put a newline and then go and print ; `f.write("%s,"%(key))` and then iterate over each row of the dataframe to write it to the file disregarding the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
dic={'key1': create_random_df() , 'key2': create_random_df()}

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in dic.keys():
        df = dic[key]
        df.insert(0,'Key', pd.Series([key]))
        df.Key = df.Key.fillna('')
        f.write(df.to_csv(index=False))
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. Follow up question: how would I name the worksheet in the excel file? i.e. one day I wanted to write onto worksheet 'x' then the next day worksheet 'y'?

Comment: in that case you need to write it to an excel. `df.to_excel`